# Error While Launching jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am using Python 3.4 version and when I am trying to open the jupyter Notebook the explorer does open but it displays a link in the explorer like this and after that nothing happens.I am not able to view anything in the explorer[image: What i can see when the explorer opens]

http://localhost:8823/tree?token=27c7f7543497392b736e1f2b74f1d6af93c2065dcbe67c61

What should I do to see the proper jupyter notebook? thanks in advance

Comment: Try with different browser to see if it would work?

Comment: When I open it in Chrome it asks for a password or Token. what password should I enter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just retype the url to

```
http://localhost:8823
```

If it still show nothing, try to run it on another non empty directory

```
jupyter notebook --notebook-dir="C:\another directory"
```

Answer (score 0):

I typed jupyter notebook list on the annaconda prompt , it then gave me a list of all the currently running servers.

i copied one of the servers in the chrome window and it worked